# yeoman error peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.5.0 wants yo@>=1.2.0

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Running `npm install -g generator-webapp` gives this at the end of the `npm-debug.log` file:

```
18875 error peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
18875 error peerinvalid Peer generator-mocha@0.1.6 wants yo@>=1.0.0
18875 error peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.5.0 wants yo@>=1.2.0
18876 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18877 error command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-webapp"
18878 error cwd c:\Users\junto\Documents\My Web Sites\kita
18879 error node -v v0.10.17
18880 error npm -v 1.3.8
18881 error code EPEERINVALID
```

Running `npm install -g yo` results in a similar error:

```
19472 error peerinvalid The package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
19472 error peerinvalid Peer generator-mocha@0.1.6 wants yo@>=1.0.0
19472 error peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.5.0 wants yo@>=1.2.0
19473 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
19474 error command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
19475 error cwd c:\Users\junto\Documents\My Web Sites\kita
19476 error node -v v0.10.17
19477 error npm -v 1.3.8
19478 error code EPEERINVALID
19479 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

You need to install yo 1.2.0

```
npm install -g yo@1.2.0
```

I had to update npm as well:

```
npm install -g npm@1.4.3
```