# unable to upgrade npm to version 1.4.3

Tags: node.js, npm, upgrade

My original problem is something similar to this post -> [yeoman error peerinvalid Peer generator-webapp@0.5.0 wants yo@>=1.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231923/yeoman-error-peerinvalid-peer-generator-webapp0-5-0-wants-yo-1-2-0)

However, I tried doing the following in the command prompt (windows machine):

```
e:\Code\html5>npm install -g npm@1.4.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.4.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.4.3
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
C:\Users\deostroll\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\deostroll\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
npm@1.4.3 C:\Users\deostroll\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm

e:\Code\html5>npm -v
1.3.21
```

Notice that I get 1.3.21 instead of 1.4.3

What is the correct way to upgrade npm?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It appears that the npm installer creates two versions on windows systems and the updates are not applied to the version used by the CLI.

This is described in more detail [here (NPM GitHub repo)](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5816) and [here (NPM GitHub Troubleshooting)](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows).
As mentioned in the GitHub repo there is a tool by microsoft that will cumbersome workaround described in the troubleshooting guide automatically for you:
https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade

You basically have to start a PowerShell as admin, install the tool and execute it:

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

See the tool's GitHub page for more info.

This helped me solve the problem, the tool lets you actually choose between any version of npm (including previous versions, alpha and beta releases).

"Don't panic" if it throws a few errors at first, it did that to me too, but everything worked fine in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using `npm update -g npm`.  Installing a parallel version is not something I've tried doing, though, if that was your intent.

Comment: Tried this, but `npm -v` shows the same result... :(